# How can I set OV certs for my website on Firebase Hosting?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, firebase-hosting

Since we had wildcard SSL certificate(OV) for our company, I wanted to set this cert to our new website on Firebase Hosting, but I couldn't find the way to set it.

Does anyone know how, or have any ideas to use both OV certs and Firebase Hosting at the same time?

There was nothing much I could do on Firebase settings page.